# Acrobat: Show field if number of check boxes with same value reaches 3

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe, acrobat

I'm creating a compliance form in Acrobat for work. Throughout the document, there's about 5 or so check boxes with the value "Amber".

I've created a warning text field that I need to be triggered to show at the moment the number of "Amber" valued check boxes checked reaches 3 or more.

So: if three or more Amber boxes are checked, an initially hidden box will appear at the bottom of the document saying so.

Thank you :) 
Mike

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: So far I thought I could get to it using using calculated fields tool, but I can't seem to get that to work at all. I assume this will be a JavaScript if/then statement? But that is certainly not my forté.